Model Derivative getModelViews request gives back a nonexistent status code
I am currently using the aps-sdk-node library, and I am calling modelDerivative.getModelViews. However, when I run it, I get this message from the library.
[server] info: 10-06-2024 16:15:23:     getModelViews Request completed successfully with status code: 204

Reading the Forge Viewer API for this, I don't see a 204 status code on it.
What does this code mean?
I don't know if this helps, but I am uploading and translating a model right before I use getModelViews. However, I know the translation and upload is complete (await) when I call getModelViews.

Could you please check what you get with the VS Code extension (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=petrbroz.vscode-forge-tools) or in e.g. Postman?
